# Docker : How to connect one container to another container via a network

Tags: docker, dockerfile, netflix-eureka

I have been researching docker with eureka, and I thought I understood how it works, but instead I have confused my self.

There is a container for the eureka server, and a container for the eureka client. The eureka client needs to be able to access the eureka server.
So what I did was find the IP address of the container which is this case is 172.20.0.2
so in my eureka client I have
defaultZone: http://172.20.0.2:8761/eureka/

I have connected both services to a network

```
"Containers": {
            "128e40236b9dc7e45cd046e34a0e2d5851a24c6da4d9510003615079c6c07a1e": {
                "Name": "bankhost",
                "EndpointID": "c5fa49a2d2d17232fa03b38835430e10eb5f40017d092b80aa624f1245bf6ec1",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "151bb21fbae965d782d0aca6fbae3cb7d24b19755bc1f01049a7e7579621e171": {
                "Name": "eurekahost",
                "EndpointID": "dd260aecffc3336b96ecfab3c7f3e36191a2672e67ca29390c359fb6b30feb2f",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
```

When I run docker compose up for my client service, it runs but I its not register with Eureka

my application.yml for Eureka server

```
server:
  port=8761
spring:
  application: eureka-service

eureka:
  client:
    validateCertificates: false
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    healthcheck:
      enabled: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

my server docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  eureka-server:
    image:  eurekaservice
    hostname: eureka-server
    container_name: eurekahost
    ports:
      - "8761:8761"
networks:
  default:
    external: true
    name: opspec
```

my application.yml for Eureka client

```
server:
  port=8080
spring:
  application: name=user-service

eureka:
  client:
    validateCertificates: true
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    healthcheck:
      enabled: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://172.20.0.2:8761/eureka/
```

Client docker-compose

```
version: '3'

services:
  bank-server:
    image:  bankservice
    hostname: bank-server
    container_name: bankhost
    ports:
      - "8083:8080"
networks:
  default:
    external: true
    name: opspec
```

Comment: "on the hoof" so just reviewing your question quickly, you should consider using a single Docker Compose file for both services. Each will then be accessible to the other by the Docker Compose service name not localhost. Docker Compose will create a network and bind both services to it. You can specify the network name type too if you need but often this is redundant.

Comment: Thank you for your reply not to sure how that would work. I always thought a docker-compose.yml needs to be in the directory where the DOCKERFILE sits. I have two different projects each has a DOCKERFILE to build the image, and a docker-compose.yml to run that DOCKERFILE . Of course now since you suggested it, I must have the wrong view on how it hangs together

Comment: Often Docker Compose references an image in a registry. But, is you reference Dockerfiles across directories, I think they may (?) all need to share a common root directory but you **can** provide the Docker Compose build step with a directory context

Comment: See the "build" section on this page: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/

Comment: When you say Docker Compose service name , do you mean the name of the container that contains the eureka server.  In my network the container name is    "Name": "eurekahost", So would i be able to use defaultZone: http://eurekahost:8761/eureka/ in my client application.yml

Comment: Thanks I got one docker-compose working for both, both services are running but they still wont connect.

Comment: When you say "they won't connect", what does happen?  To reiterate @DazWilkin's suggestion, the Compose service names `eureka-server` and `bank-server` should be usable as host names; you do not typically need to specify `hostname:` or `container_name:` nor do you need to manually look up IP addresses.

Comment: Ok in Euraka Client which us the bank-server, it needs to be able to call the eureka-server. So if I was running ooutside the containers in my bankservice application.yml I would have the following  serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/ this will register the bankservice with the eureka-server.   Now they are in two different containers, and I need to work out what should replace localhost. So that my bankservice can register with the eureka-service

Answer (score -1):

All I really need to know is what do I need to put in the my application.yml for Eureka client

for  defaultZone: http://XXXXXXXXX:8761/eureka/

All I need to know is what XXXXXXXX should be then I can work backwords.

There is the name of the container that contains the Eureka Server
The IP address of of the container that contains the Eureka Server
The service name of the image
And even  0.0.0.0